# OpenGL 1.1 + SDL2 + SDL_TTF Text Render Transparency

Tags: c++, opengl, sdl, sdl-2, sdl-ttf

I'm trying to write simple gui in c++ with opengl+sdl2, but now I have problem with text rendering.

This is what I get on my old laptop with opengl 1.1(notice white rectangle):

[image: screenshot_opengl1.1]

and this on my pc:

[image: screenshot_working]

This is my function for text rendering:

```
void drawText(std::string text,TTF_Font * font,GLubyte R,GLubyte G,GLubyte B,GLubyte A,float X,float Y,float Z=0){
  SDL_Color color={R,G,B,A};
  SDL_Surface *msg = TTF_RenderUTF8_Blended(font,text.c_str(),color);
  GLuint texture=0;
  glGenTextures(1,&texture);
  glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D,texture);
  GLuint texture_format;
  int wW,wH;
  SDL_GetWindowSize(window,&wW,&wH);
  int colors = msg->format->BytesPerPixel;
    if (colors == 4) {   // alpha
      if (msg->format->Rmask == 0x000000ff)
        texture_format = GL_RGBA;
      else
        texture_format = GL_BGRA_EXT;
    } else {             // no alpha
      if (msg->format->Rmask == 0x000000ff)
        texture_format = GL_RGB;
      else
        texture_format = GL_BGR_EXT;
    }
  float MsgWP=msg->w*1.0/wW;
  float MsgHP=msg->h*1.0/wH;
  int dX=-1;
  int dY=1;
  X*=2;
  Y*=2;
  glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, colors,msg->w,msg->h,0,texture_format,GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,msg->pixels);
  glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
  glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
  glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
  glEnable(GL_BLEND);
  glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA,GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
  glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glColor3f(1,1,1);
    glTexCoord2f(0,0); glVertex2f(dX+X+0     ,  dY-Y+0);
    glTexCoord2f(1,0); glVertex2f(dX+X+MsgWP ,  dY-Y+0);
    glTexCoord2f(1,1); glVertex2f(dX+X+MsgWP ,  dY-Y-MsgHP);
    glTexCoord2f(0,1); glVertex2f(dX+X+0     ,  dY-Y-MsgHP);
  glEnd();
  glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
  glDeleteTextures(1,&texture);
  SDL_FreeSurface(msg);
}
```

Now I have a question: Why on lower version of opengl text is not rendering correctly?

Comment: I suppose that TTF text renderer uses an OpenGL extension that is not present on older version. Can't you update the video card drivers? Also check if this statement is needed: if (msg->format->Rmask == 0x000000ff). Maybe you  need GL_RGBA after all?

Comment: @VuVirt When I save texture with SDL_SaveBMP text is rendered correctly

Comment: Did you verify that the laptop's OpenGL implementation actually supports [`EXT_bgra`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/extensions/EXT/EXT_bgra.txt)?

Comment: @genpfault Yes ,I checked it with GPU Caps Viewer(GL_EXT_bgra (OpenGL 1.2))

Comment: Sorry I miss wrote it. I meant when I opened saved file the alpha was correct.